# In GNU screen, how do you reload .bashrc in all windows?

Tags: gnu-screen

I typically use about 10 windows in GNU screen and am constantly customizing my `.bashrc`.  I would like to be able to source `.bashrc` across screen windows with a one-liner.  Can I broadcast a command to all my screen windows without detaching my session, running the command (in this case, sourcing the profile) and re-attaching to the screen session?  I use Mac OS 10.8.

I believe [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/204611/gnu-screen-execute-command-on-attach) will also work for what I want to do, but I'm curious as to whether there is a more concise way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Screen User Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html), you can send arbitrary text to all screen windows via it's -X command line argument combined with the builtin screen commands **at** and **stuff** with the following command, in your case

```
screen -X at \# stuff "source ~/.bashrc\n"
```

Keep in mind that this command is the equivalent to typing "source ~/.bashrc" in to every window. If a window isn't at a bash prompt and is instead say, editing a file with vim, it will have some unexpected results.